# How to Send POST Request in windows Phone 8 and get its Response in json

Tags: c#, post, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am trying to call a web service 
which returns a JSON response. So far my code is working fine for GET Request but now services on server are POST and I have no idea how to do that! Below is the code for GET Request:

```
 private void callSigninWebservice()
        {
            setProgressIndicator(true);

            SystemTray.ProgressIndicator.Text = "Signing in please wait";
            try
            {
                WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
                Uri uri = new Uri(GlobalVariables.URL_USER +
                GlobalVariables.URL_STUDENT_SIGNIN_MODE_LOGIN +
                GlobalVariables.URL_EMAIL + tbUsername.Text +
                GlobalVariables.URL_PASSWORD + tbPassword.Password);
                webClient.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(webClient_DownloadStringCompleted);
                webClient.DownloadStringAsync(uri);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + "error came here 1");
            }

        }
```

For Response

```
void webClient_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {

                JObject parentObj = JObject.Parse(e.Result);
                String strResult = (String)parentObj[SigninData.JSON_result];

                bool bolresult = strResult.Equals(SigninData.JSON_result_success, StringComparison.Ordinal);

                if (bolresult)
                {
                    JObject dataObj = (JObject)parentObj[SigninData.JSON_data];
                    setUserData(dataObj);
                    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/BasePage.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));

                }
                else
                {
                    String error = (String)parentObj[SigninData.JSON_data];
                    MessageBox.Show("Error : " + error);
                }
                setProgressIndicator(false);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                setProgressIndicator(false);
            }

        }
```

Comment: [check this](http://www.jayway.com/2012/03/13/httpclient-makes-get-and-post-very-simple/)

Comment: This is not helping . @vits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple way of making a post request and receiving a response in JSON for future parse:

```
    internal static async Task<String> GetHttpPostResponse(HttpWebRequest request, string postData)
    {
        String received = null;

        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        byte[] requestBody = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);

        // ASYNC: using awaitable wrapper to get request stream
        using (var postStream = await request.GetRequestStreamAsync())
        {
            // Write to the request stream.
            // ASYNC: writing to the POST stream can be slow
            await postStream.WriteAsync(requestBody, 0, requestBody.Length);
        }

        try
        {
            // ASYNC: using awaitable wrapper to get response
            var response = (HttpWebResponse)await request.GetResponseAsync();
            if (response != null)
            {
                var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
                // ASYNC: using StreamReader's async method to read to end, in case
                // the stream i slarge.
                received = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
            }
        }
        catch (WebException we)
        {
            var reader = new StreamReader(we.Response.GetResponseStream());
            string responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();
            Debug.WriteLine(responseString);
            return responseString;
        }

        return received;
    }
```

Comment: 'System.Net.HttpWebRequest' does not contain a definition for 'GetRequestStreamAsync' and no extension method 'GetRequestStreamAsync' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Net.HttpWebRequest' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) this is the error im getting

Comment: Please install the **Microsoft HTTP Client Library** from NuGet and that should solve your problem.

Comment: @Meneses, Microsoft HTTP Client Library seems to be for wp8.1 and not wp8

Comment: @eeadev You seem to be right regarding the current version. If you want to use it in Windows Phone 8, you can always use the NuGet command `Install-Package Microsoft.Net.Http -Version 2.2.19` as this version still supports Windows Phone 8.

Comment: @Meneses, I am new to C#, what would be the clause using in this case?

Comment: @eeadev I think it should be `using microsoft.net.http`